# react-native-video-controls doesn't seek well inside scrollview

Tags: react-native, react-native-video, panresponder

I have a video inside a scrollview, and the child video player propagates the gesture to the scrollview, which results in some *weird* behavior. How do I make react-native-video-controls only respond to horizontal gestures, or at least prevent the propagation up to the parent scrollview?

Comment: have you tried `scrollEnabled={false}` for ScrollView?

Comment: I need the view to scroll - just not when touching that child component. The scroll of the parent container messes up the seeking with the panhandler in the child.

Comment: yeah interesting issue. lemme think about it.

Comment: did you think about it?